# Is it possible to change content of layout thought props?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have that layout:

```
<template>
  ...navigation for all pages..
  <h1>content for X??</h1>
  <slot />
  ...footer for all pages...
</template>
```

For pages/index.vue:

```
<template>
  index is here ok :)
</template>
```

and pages/about.vue:

```
<template>
 about is here ok :)
</template>
```

I wish I could render h1 in layout for different pages and not print same text for all.

I know I can move h1 from layout to pages and edit each page.

But there are a lot of content between h1 and slot and I just want to change text.

Comment: You can use Pinia or Vuex to have a global state that you can then access into the layout.

Comment: The simpliest way could be storing the message in a variable at the parent-most component. And on page changed mutate this variable

Comment: @HuyPhạm the `default` template (I assume) is already quite high level, don't recommend trying to put anything higher.

Comment: If your text inside h1 is static then you can pass props in route also. I assume that each page has a different route and each route has a layout, so in the route's meta-property, you can pass additional data and access this data on any page in your application. For more information [read here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html#route-meta-fields).

Comment: @GeorgesA that kind of behavior is unfortunately forbidden on SO. Please refrain from it. Especially since you're not answering to the main part of the question ([layouts](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts)).

Answer (score 0):

There would be many ways of achieving what you are asking but the simplest would be the usage of named slots.

In the [vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots) (please take some time digging into it, the amount of deftail and explanation available is very appreciable) :

> The `<slot>` element has a special attribute, name, which can be used to assign a unique ID to different slots so you can determine where content should be rendered.

The process of using named slots in the nuxt layouts is documented in the [nuxt layout documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts#overriding-a-layout-on-a-per-page-basis).
You could create a `TitleLayout.vue` component in the `layouts` folder of your nuxt project that would look like this:

```html
<!-- layouts/TitleLayout.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <nuxt-link to="/"> index </nuxt-link>
            <nuxt-link to="about"> about </nuxt-link>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <h1>
                <slot name="heading">
                    a default title
                </slot>
            </h1>
            <slot/>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>
```

and that you could use it like this in your `pages/About.vue` (or in any other page)

```html
<!-- pages/About.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <NuxtLayout name="with-title">
            <template #heading> Hello from the about title </template>

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam eius
            rem, sit repellendus reiciendis explicabo? Dolorum totam molestias
            adipisci cupiditate distinctio, libero dolorem iusto, quidem esse
            excepturi voluptatem repellendus facere.

        </NuxtLayout>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'titleLayout',
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're not using the layout feature of Nuxt here tho, but rather a usual component where you're nesting some markup. Your example is quite different from what OP asks and hence your answer misses the point.

Comment: @kissu Updated response using the proper nuxt components. Regarding your comment, I think OP is not asking the proper question regarding the problem he is explaining. I'm offering a solution that has a better maintanability and that moves away from the react way of using props.

Comment: Again, not using Nuxt layouts here and I'm not sure where you saw a React pattern neither.

Comment: The code is litterally using the NuxtLayout component and I just added the forgotten <script> tag. I saw a react pattern when op was looking for a way of passing data to be displayed as props, but I agree that I might be overthinking that one.